# Looking for a specific puzzle game

Tags: puzzle-identification

There was a puzzle game on ZX-Spectrum computer called "Logo: Part I": http://www.worldofspectrum.org/pub/sinclair/screens/in-game/l/Logo-PartI.gif

Basically, you can put tokens on the board; the newly put token becomes 1; old neighbours are increased; if a neighbour was 4, it becomes 1 again; the goal is to get the specific configuration for each level.

I'd want to know if there are other names or implementations of this puzzle. Is it well-known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

This seems to be a variant of [Lights Out](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html), except switches that haven't been pressed don't 'exist' yet.